# Django Querysets - add a string literal annotation

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to literally add a string to a queryset object.  Why, because I'm sending this to JSON and it would be so nice and clean to just put the information there and have it available without having to iterate over the queryset to turn it into a custom dictionary.

What I have now:

```
a_vote_set.aggregate(
                    count = Count('id'),
                    avg=Avg('score'),
                    std=StdDev('score'),
                    sum=Sum('score'),
                )
```

Which gets me this:

```
{"count": 1, "std": 0.0, "sum": -4.0, "avg": -4.0}
```

What I want to get is:

```
{"count": 1, "std": 0.0, "sum": -4.0, "avg": -4.0, "additional_value": "name of candidate"}
```

Which I would love to get by calling something like this:

```
    a_vote_set.aggregate(
                        count = Count('id'),
                        avg=Avg('score'),
                        std=StdDev('score'),
                        sum=Sum('score'),
                        additional_value=Literal(candidate.name),
                    )

or this:

    a_vote_set.aggregate(
                        count = Count('id'),
                        avg=Avg('score'),
                        std=StdDev('score'),
                        sum=Sum('score')
                 ).append(
                        additional_value=str(candidate.name),
                 )
```

Any ideas on if this is possible?

Answer (score 13):

You can add literal value with [Value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions):

```py
from django.db import models

a_vote_set.aggregate(
    count = Count('id'),
    avg=Avg('score'),
    std=StdDev('score'),
    sum=Sum('score')
).annotate(
    additional_value=models.Value(candidate.name, output_field=models.CharField()),
)
```

Comment: I think this would only work if the model has the field `additional_value`, else you get `FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra) something like:

```
a_vote_set.aggregate(
                    count = Count('id'),
                    avg=Avg('score'),
                    std=StdDev('score'),
                    sum=Sum('score'),

                ).extra(
                       select={
                              'additional_value' : 'candidate_table.name' 
                              }, 
                       where=['candidate_table.id = vote_table.candidate_id']
                )
```

You may also be able to pass Q() and F() values into the select, but I'm not sure.

Comment: DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'table.field' in 'field list'")

Comment: @est what are you getting at?

Comment: ok, I solved the problem by add `tables=[]` parameter. But the results are not inner join, but inter-multiplied like a matrix.